# ¿Porque al imprimir la matriz cuando doy de alta varios productos se sobreescriben algunos datos?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa de un inventario, al dar de alta los productos mediante el menu y opción altas se muestra el inventario hasta ese momento, el problema es que al volver a ingresar un producto se sobre escribe la fecha y se cambia por un numero.

Lo que sucede es que se pregunta en altas cuantos productos va ingresar, despues el nombre, cantidad, costo, precio y eso se guarda en un array tipo string y busco que al imprrimir el inventario aparezcan estos datos, solo que al escribir mas de un produto algunos valores sobrescriben la fecha.

```
int main(){

    string nombrecliente, usuario, contrasena, s,  respuesta, respuestaproductos;
    string CAMBIOS[4][1], INVENTARIO[4][5];

    int i, n, l, k, opcion, opcion_menu, opcion_reportes, valido, respu, cantidadinv, respuproductos;
    int cantcambios[4], inventario[4][2];

    i=0, k=0, n=0, l=0;
    respu=0, respuproductos=0;
    valido = 1;
    cantidadinv=0;

    system ("CLS");
    do{
        cout<<"Usuario: ";
        getline(cin, usuario);
        cout<<"Contrasena: ";
        getline(cin, contrasena);

        if(usuario == "a" and contrasena == "1")
        {
            opcion = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(usuario == "usuario 1" and contrasena == "Udem2023")
            {
                 opcion = 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                if(usuario == "usuario 2" and contrasena == "Udem2024")
                {
                     opcion = 2;
                }
                else{
                    cout<<"Usuario o contrasena incorrectos"<<endl;
                    system ("PAUSE");
                    system ("CLS");
                }
                
            }
        }
    }while ((opcion != 1) and (opcion != 2));
    

    menu:
        if (opcion == 1){    
            do{
                system ("CLS");
                cout<<"--- MENU ---\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"1: Inventario\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"2: Reportes\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"0: Salir\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"Opcion: ";
                cin>>opcion_menu;
            }while (opcion_menu != 1 and opcion_menu != 2 and opcion_menu != 0);
        }
        else{
            do{
                system ("CLS");
                cout<<"--- MENU ---\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"1: Inventario\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"0: Salir\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"Opcion: ";
                cin>>opcion_menu;
            }while (opcion_menu != 1 and opcion_menu != 0);
        }
    switch (opcion_menu){
        case 1:
            do{
                submenuinv:
                    menuinventario();
                    cin>>opcion_menu;
            }while (opcion_menu != 1 and opcion_menu != 2 and opcion_menu != 3 and opcion_menu != 0);
            
            switch (opcion_menu)
            {
                case 1:
                    do{
                        altas:
                            system ("CLS");
                            cout<<"--- ALTAS ---\n"<<endl;
                            cout<<"1: Ingresar Producto\n"<<endl;
                            cout<<"0: Regresar\n"<<endl;
                            cout<<"Opcion: ";
                            cin>>opcion_menu;
                    }while (opcion_menu != 0 and opcion_menu != 1);
                    
                    if (opcion_menu == 0){
                        goto submenuinv;
                    }
                    else{
                        do{
                            do{
                                system ("CLS");
                                cout<<"Cuantos productos ingresaras? (cantidad max 5, actualmente llevas "<<cantidadinv<<")"<<endl;
                                cin>>respuesta;  
                                s=respuesta;
                                valido=validarnum(s);
                            }while(valido==0);
                            respu=stoi(respuesta);
                            if ((cantidadinv+respu>5)){
                                cout<<"Numero de elementos maximos superados"<<endl;
                                system("PAUSE");
                            }
                        }while(respu+cantidadinv > 5);

                        for (i = cantidadinv; i < cantidadinv+respu; i++){
                            system ("CLS");
                            INVENTARIO[i][0]=to_string(l);
                            cout<<"Ingresa los datos para ingresar un producto al sistema:\n"<<endl;
                            do{
                                if (valido==0){
                                    cout<<"Ingresa los datos para ingresar un producto al sistema:\n"<<endl;
                                }
                                cout<<"Nombre del Producto "<<i<<": ";
                                cin.ignore();
                                getline(cin, INVENTARIO[i][1]);
                                s=INVENTARIO[i][1];
                                valido=validarletras(s);
                            }while(valido==0);
                            do{
                                if (valido==0){
                                    cout<<"Ingresa los datos para ingresar un producto al sistema:\n"<<endl;
                                    cout<<"Producto:"<<INVENTARIO[i][1]<<endl;
                                }
                                cout<<"Cantidad: ";
                                cin>>INVENTARIO[i][2];
                                s=INVENTARIO[i][2];
                                valido=validarnum(s);
                                if (valido==1){
                                    inventario[i][0]=stoi(INVENTARIO[i][2]);
                                }
                            }while(valido==0);
                            do{
                                if (valido==0){
                                    cout<<"Ingresa los datos para ingresar un producto al sistema:\n"<<endl;
                                    cout<<"Producto:"<<INVENTARIO[i][1]<<endl;
                                    cout<<"Cantidad:"<<INVENTARIO[i][2]<<endl;
                                }
                                cout<<"Costo: $";
                                cin>>INVENTARIO[i][3];
                                s=INVENTARIO[i][3];
                                valido=validarnumdecimal(s);
                                if (valido==1){
                                    inventario[i][1]=stoi(INVENTARIO[i][3]);
                                }                               
                            }while(valido==0);
                            do{
                                if (valido==0){
                                    cout<<"Ingresa los datos para ingresar un producto al sistema:\n"<<endl;
                                    cout<<"Producto:"<<INVENTARIO[i][1]<<endl;
                                    cout<<"Cantidad:"<<INVENTARIO[i][2]<<endl;
                                    cout<<"Costo:$"<<INVENTARIO[i][3]<<endl;
                                }
                                cout<<"Precio de Lista: $";
                                cin>>INVENTARIO[i][4];
                                s=INVENTARIO[i][4];
                                valido=validarnumdecimal(s);
                                if (valido==1){
                                    inventario[i][2]=stoi(INVENTARIO[i][4]);
                                }    
                            }while(valido==0);
                            time_t now = time(0);
                            char* date_time = ctime(&now);
                            INVENTARIO[i][5]=date_time;
                            cout<<"Fecha de Ingreso: "<<INVENTARIO[i][5]<<endl;

                            cout<<endl;
                            cout<<"Producto ingresado correctamente"<<endl;
                            l++;
                            system("PAUSE");
                        }  
                        cantidadinv=cantidadinv+respu;
                        invent(INVENTARIO, cantidadinv);
                        system("PAUSE");
                        goto submenuinv;
                    }
                break;
                case 2:
                    do{
                        submenucambios:
                            system ("CLS");
                            cout<<"--- CAMBIOS ---\n"<<endl;
                            cout<<"1: Generar ticket de venta\n"<<endl;
                            cout<<"0: Regresar\n"<<endl;
                            cout<<"Opcion: ";
                            cin>>opcion_menu;
                    }while (opcion_menu != 0 and opcion_menu != 1);
                    
                    if (opcion_menu == 0){
                        goto submenuinv;
                    }

                    if (opcion_menu == 1){
                        system ("CLS");

                        do{
                            system ("CLS");
                            if (respuproductos>5){
                                cout<<"Numero superior a 5"<<endl;
                                system("PAUSE");
                                system("CLS");
                            }
                            cout<<"Cuantos productos diferentes compra? (cantidad max 5)"<<endl;
                            cin>>respuestaproductos;
                            s=respuestaproductos;
                            valido=validarnum(s);
                            if (valido==1){
                                respuproductos=stoi(respuestaproductos);
                            }
                        }while(valido==0 or respuproductos>5);   

                        system("CLS");
                        cout<<"Ingrese los datos para generar el ticket de venta:"<<endl;
                        do{
                            if (valido==0){
                                system("CLS");
                                cout<<"Ingrese los datos para generar el ticket de venta:"<<endl;
                            }
                            cout<<"Nombre del Cliente: ";
                            cin.ignore();
                            getline(cin, nombrecliente);
                            s=nombrecliente;
                            valido=validarletras(s);
                        }while(valido==0);

                        for(k=0; k<respuproductos; k++){
                            do{
                                do{
                                    if (valido==0){
                                        n++;
                                        cout<<"No existe ningun producto con ese nombre"<<endl;
                                        system("PAUSE");
                                        system("CLS");
                                        cout<<"Ingrese los datos para generar el ticket de venta:"<<endl;
                                        cout<<"Nombre del Cliente: "<<nombrecliente<<endl;
                                    }

                                    system("CLS");
                                    invent(INVENTARIO, cantidadinv);
                                    cout<<endl;

                                    cout<<"Nombre del Producto "<<k<<": ";
                                    getline(cin, CAMBIOS[k][0]);
                                    if (CAMBIOS[k][0]!=INVENTARIO[n][1]){
                                        valido=0;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        valido=1;
                                    }
                                }while(valido==0);

                                if (inventario[n][0]<=0){
                                    cout<<"Lo sentimos actualmente no hay cantidad del producto "<<CAMBIOS[k][0]<<endl;
                                    valido=0;
                                    system("PAUSE");
                                    goto submenuinv;
                                }    
                            }while(valido==0);  
                            do{
                                do{
                                    if (valido==0){
                                        cout<<"La cantidad no es valida"<<endl;
                                        system("PAUSE");
                                        system("CLS");
                                        cout<<"Ingrese los datos para generar el ticket de venta:"<<endl;
                                        cout<<"Nombre del Cliente: "<<nombrecliente<<endl;
                                        cout<<"Nombre del Producto: "<<CAMBIOS[k][0]<<endl;
                                    }
                                    cout<<"Cantidad: ";
                                    cin>>CAMBIOS[k][1];
                                    s=CAMBIOS[k][1];
                                    valido=validarnum(s);
                                    if (valido==1){
                                        cantcambios[k]=stoi(CAMBIOS[k][1]);
                                    }
                                }while(valido==0);      
                                if(valido==1 and inventario[n][0]>0){
                                    if (cantcambios[k]>inventario[n][0]){
                                        valido=0;
                                    }
                                    if (cantcambios[k]<=inventario[n][0]){
                                        inventario[n][0]=inventario[n][0]-cantcambios[1];
                                    }
                                }                
                            }while(valido==0);                      
                                
                            cout<<"\nDatos ingresados correctamente"<<endl<<"Presiona cualquier tecla para ver el ticket de compra "<<endl;
                            system("PAUSE>nul");
                        }
                        goto submenucambios;
                    }

                break;
                case 3:
                    do{
                        system ("CLS");
                        cout<<"--- BAJAS ---"<<endl;
                        cout<<"Ingresa los datos para dar de baja un producto del sistema\n"<<endl;
                        cout<<"Producto:\n"<<endl;
                        cout<<"Cantidad:\n"<<endl;
                        cout<<"0: Regresar\n"<<endl;
                        cout<<"Opcion: ";
                        cin>>opcion_menu;
                    }while (opcion_menu != 0);
                    
                    if (opcion_menu == 0){
                        goto submenuinv;
                    }

                break;
                case 0:
                    goto menu;
                    
                break;
            }
        break;
        case 2:
            do{
                submenureportes:
                    system ("CLS");
                    cout<<"--- REPORTES ---\n"<<endl;
                    cout<<"1: Diario\n"<<endl;
                    cout<<"2: Semanal\n"<<endl;
                    cout<<"0: Regresar\n"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Opcion: ";
                    cin>>opcion_reportes;
            }while (opcion_reportes != 1 and opcion_reportes != 2 and opcion_reportes != 0);

            switch (opcion_reportes)
            {
                case 1:
                    system ("CLS");
                    cout<<"Tu reporte diario:"<<endl;

                    cout<<"Presiona cualquier tecla para continuar ";
                    system("PAUSE>nul");
                    goto submenureportes;
                break;
                case 2:
                    system("CLS");
                    cout<<"Tu reporte semanal:"<<endl;

                    cout<<"Presiona cualquier tecla para continuar ";
                    system("PAUSE>nul");
                    goto submenureportes;
                break;
                case 0:
                    goto menu;

                break;
            }
        break;
        case 0:
            system ("CLS");
            cout<<"Adios, que tengas buen dia";
            return 0;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void menuinventario(){
    system ("CLS");
    cout<<"--- INVENTARIO ---\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"1: Altas\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"2: Cambios\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"3: Bajas\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"0: Regresar\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"Opcion: ";
}
int validarletras(string s){
    int n = s.length();
    char char_array[n + 1];
    strcpy(char_array, s.c_str());

    for (int i= 0; i < n; i++){
        if ((isalpha(char_array[i])==0)){
            if (isspace(char_array[i])==false){
                cout<<"No es valido (Solo letras y espacios) "<<endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                system("CLS");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }   
    return 1;
}
int validarnum(string s){
    int n = s.length();
    char char_array[n + 1];
    strcpy(char_array, s.c_str());
 
    for (int i= 0; i < n; i++){
        if ((isdigit(char_array[i])==false)){
            cout<<"No es valido (Solo numeros positivos (enteros))"<<endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
            return 0;
        }
    }   
    return 1;
}
int validarnumdecimal(string s){
    int m;
    int n = s.length();
    char char_array[n + 1];
    m=0;
    strcpy(char_array, s.c_str());
 
    for (int i= 0; i < n; i++){
        if ((isdigit(char_array[i])==false)){
            if (m!=0 and (isdigit(char_array[i])==false)){
                cout<<"No es valido (Solo numeros (positivos))"<<endl;;
                system("PAUSE");
                system("CLS");
                return 0;
            }
            if ((isdigit(char_array[i])==false) and char_array[i]!='.'){
                cout<<"No es valido (Solo numeros (positivos))"<<endl;;
                system("PAUSE");
                system("CLS");                
                return 0;
            }
            if (char_array[i]=='.'){
                m=m+1;
            }
        }
    }   
    return 1;
}
int invent( string innventario[][5], int canti){
    int i, j;
    system("CLS");
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout<< "Inventario\n" << endl;
    cout<< "#P\tNombre\tCant\tCosto\tPVenta\tFecha de Ingreso"<< endl;
    for (i=0; i< canti; i++){
        for (j=0; j< 6; j++){
            cout << innventario[i][j] <<"\t" ;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: El código es largo así que quiero leerlo detenidamente. Pero vi que usas `goto`s lo cual está desaconsejado. Siempre que puedas usa funciones o hazlo de otra manera. Solo úsalos como último recurso. Hacen el código más difícil de leer y seguir el flujo del programa.

Comment: Gracias, es que no sabría como implementar las funciones para poder regresar de los menús, soy nuevo y apenas voy empezando.

Comment: Sean dos funciones **A** y **B**, cuando **A** llama a **B**, **A** se detiene y le entrega el control a **B**. Cuando **B** termina, le regresa el control a **A** y **A** continúa con lo que estaba haciendo. Con `goto` lo que haces es saltar de un lado a otro. Así te pierdes más fácil que con una función.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué procedimiento estás siguiendo? Me refiero a los datos que le das al programa por consola. Con copiarla y pegarla está bien.

Comment: Nombre del Producto 0: Tijera 
Cantidad: 2
Costo: $10
Precio de Lista: $15Nombre del Producto 1: Hojas
Cantidad: 2
Costo: $5
Precio de Lista: $8. Lo que sucede cuando los ingreso es que se reescribe el valor de la fecha y escribe un numero 1.

Comment: Otra pregunta hay alguna forma de validar un int para que solo se ingresen numeros es decir que al ingresar letras o caracteres especiales no lo tome y vuela a preguntar, ya que con el uso de strings se vuelve mucho mas complicado por stoi y demas. Gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140620/discussion-between-zekeriyasusuzz-and-mateo).